# How can I do a zone transfer with dig when using bind views

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dig

I have a bind cluster with private/public records stored in (2) views and configured with TSIG.  Standard slave operation works but I'd like to use dig to transfer the zones for troubleshooting/testing.

Typically I'd use `dig example.com @ns1.example.com -y tsig-key:SECRETCODE` however this is denied as the key is only assigned to the view public.

Reproduce:
Attempt a dig axfr from a client in the internal view.

Transfer Fails:

```
dig AXFR example.com -y external:xxxxxxxx
```

Transfer Succeeds

```
dig AXFR example.com -y internal:xxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply set up an additional key for the internal view and configure bind to allow the key to act as a selector for a specific view:

```
key "external" {
  algorithm hmac-md5;
  secret "xxxxxxxx";
};
key "internal" {
  algorithm hmac-md5;
  secret "yyyyyyyy";
};
view "internal" {
  match-clients { key internal; 10.0.1/24; };
  server 10.0.1.1 {
    /* Deliver notify messages to external view. */
    keys { external; };
  };
  zone "example.com" {
    type master;
    file "internal/example.db";
    ...
  };
};
view "external" {
  match-clients { key external; any; };
  zone "example.com" {
    type master;
    file "external/example.db";
    ...
  };
};
```

Comment: works for bind, not for dig.